# Django Fixture Load on Google App Engine Very Slow

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

I've deployed a Django website using Google App Engine, and am using the command

```
python manage.py remote loaddata my_data.yaml
```

to populate the datastore with initial data from a fixture file in yaml format.  Here is a sample of my yaml file:

```
- fields: {team: 10, first_name: Jeff, last_name: Adrien, age: 25, pos: SF, gp: 8, mp: 63, 
fg: 7, fga: 16, ft: 7, fta: 12, three_pointers: 0, threes_attempted: 0, orb: 5, drb: 17, 
ast: 1, stl: 0, blk: 2, tov: 2, pf: 13, pts: 21
}
  model: players.player
  pk: 1
- fields: {team: 7, first_name: Arron, last_name: Afflalo, age: 26, pos: SG, gp: 62, mp: 2086, 
fg: 329, fga: 699, ft: 197, fta: 247, three_pointers: 88, threes_attempted: 221, orb: 40, 
drb: 157, ast: 149, stl: 36, blk: 13, tov: 85, pf: 134, pts: 943
}
  model: players.player
  pk: 2
```

The total yaml file is approximately 20 times this size (it goes to pk: 478).  I didn't think that was so big, but it's taking an incredibly long time (several minutes) to load into the datastore even though I have a pretty fast network connection (1 Mbps).

On top of that, after loading it, I check the Dashboard on Google App Engine and it says I've performed 0.04 million write operations on the datastore.  By my calculations, given that I have 21 fields above, plus one for the pk, times 478 model instances, I should only be performing about 10K writes, not 40K.

Are the additional writes happening because I'm using django-dbindexer to add indexes for the first_name and last_name fields?  And if so, is that why it's taking so long to load my data?

Answer (score 2):

The remote API is really slow.  If you read up on the old google-appengine-python mailing list (you can find it in Google Groups), it's been noted that it's not useful for mass data transfers.  The API ends up making an HTTP request for each read or write request.  So this is known.  The bulkloader seems to be the way to go to load mass data (I haven't tried it personally).

Your writes are dependent on the number of indexed properties you have, which in turn depends on the number of indexes you have.  It's possible that dbindexer is adding additional indexed fields.  You should be able to look at the actual entities in your datastore using the Datastore Admin, to see if they have dbindexer generated fields.  You'll see extra fields like "idxf_first_name_iexact" if it's dbindexer's fault.

More likely is that you're doing some complicated queries that require additional indexes to be written for each entity.  You should be able to look at the Datastore Indexes page in the admin to see the number of extra indexes you write per entity.

Another way indexes grow faster than you expect is if you have an indexed list property, but it doesn't look like you have that.

I suggest that you be very skeptical of dbindexer.  I haven't used it extensively, but the JOIN operations it can do for you won't scale well, so in my mind, it's just a toy and not a usable feature.  There's probably still a few things you can use it for.  For example if you want to do case insensitive searches, it'll automatically add an 'iexact' field for you, rather than having to do that manually.